# Playing mocap animations in THREE.js gives "No Target Node Found" error

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, theia, unreal

I have motion capture .fbx files from a Qualisys system, exported from Theia. I'm not part of the capture process so I'm not 100% on the details there. Unfortunately, the format of the bones in the .fbx file don't seem to line up with anything I need them for. I want to use them in Unity and Unreal Engine, which require retargeting. I also want to display them using THREE.js, and that brings me here.

I've converted the .fbx file to a .glb file and have the mesh displayed in THREE.js, but it wont animate. To play the animation I'm using:

```
loader.load(path, async function ( mdl ) {
        if(mdl.animations.length > 0)
        {
            console.log(`Loading animations for ${data.name}: ${mdl.animations.length}`);
            scene.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mdl );
            scene.action = scene.mixer.clipAction(mdl.animations[0]);
            scene.action.play();
        }
}
```

The model is showing, and I see my console.log showing 2 animations. But then the console shows these errors (shown for every bone, I've just shown a few) :

```
THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: person_0pelvis.position. three.module.js:48585:12
THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: person_0pelvis.quaternion. three.module.js:48585:12
THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: person_0pelvis.scale. three.module.js:48585:12
THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: person_0abdomen.position. three.module.js:48585:12
THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: person_0abdomen.quaternion. three.module.js:48585:12
THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: person_0abdomen.scale. three.module.js:48585:12
THREE.PropertyBinding: No target node found for track: person_0thorax.position.
```

I can't find much information about the error, though [using this tool](https://www.creators3d.com/online-viewer) the animation does play just fine so I'm sure it's something on my end.

Just in case anyone else has experience with mocap data from Theia, I feel like there must be a way to export the animation that works with things like Unity, Unreal, or Mixamo? It's so hard to find any information about it. I'd love any tips or links! Thanks

I tried exporting the model with various settings from Blender. I also tried Google but found nothing.